# jest: get runtime config object or file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I was wondering if it's possible to get the jest runtime config object or filepath.

My use case would be to use various runtime config properties on my custom matchers

```js
// ./jest.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  prop1: "foo",
  prop2: "bar"
};
```

```js
// my-custom-matcher.js
expect.extend({
  matcherName(received: any, pathToFile: string) {
    const relativeDir = path.join(runtimeconfigpath, pathToFile); // i need the path to the runtimeconfigpath being used here
    const baz = runtimeconfig.foo // or access the config properties like this
  }
});
```

I tried various stuff and dug around the docs but i dont see this anywhere.
The nearest possible alternative I can think of would be to use config globals but that would complicate stuff if 'preset' and config extensions come into play.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply import `jest.config.js`? Or is there a specific reason not to import it? At least it is loaded by jest itself, so you should be fine by just importing it.

> As js code is only compiled once and the reused of other files also need it

Otherwise you could look into [5 Advanced npm package.json configuration tips](https://davidwells.io/blog/advanced-package-json-tips) and see if it helps.

Or crate a recursive function that searches for the file. Maybe there is even some way to instantly get the path to `package.json` and then you can use this to continue from there (I did not find it after a short search)